# How to create several web roles, which are using https, within one Hosted Service

Tags: configuration, azure

I have several web application (2 web applications and 1 WCF Service). I want to have https for web applications. But I want to keep the web applications -> WCF communication internal using http/tcp. While the WCF Service should have the possibility to expose https communication to outside as well. So the question is:

Is it possible to deploy web applications and WCF Service as one Hosted Service in Azure? Then how to forward to the correct application, as each of those do not have unique dns name?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple roles listening on the same port, so if your web site and your WCF services all need port 443, they'll all have to be part of the same web role.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, it is possible to have multiple web app and (WCF) services in the same hosted service, colocated in one web role or splitted over different web roles according to how much you need to scale with precision (ie: add more instances to the service but not to the sites).

You will not be able to specify different custom domain names, as the domain name http://.cloudapp.net is at the hosted service level. You can just have 
http://.cloudapp.net/service and http://.cloudapp.net/web in the same hosted service.

Each of the [new web sites](https://www.windowsazure.com/it-it/home/scenarios/web-sites/) has its own domain name in shared mode but the ability to have a custom domain is only available in reserved mode.